# Android: Send Key Inputs to System / other Apps without Root

Tags: android, keyboard, root

is it possible to send key inputs (events) to the system or other apps by an app without using root?

Background of my question:

I'm having an app that sends key inputs (text) to the system every some seconds.
But my code requires root access and now a user asked, if it's possible to release my app without the need of root access.

This is my current code (requires a rooted device):

```
private void typeText(String sText) {
    CommandCapture command = new CommandCapture(0, "input text " + sText);
    try {
        RootTools.getShell(true).add(command).waitForFinish();
    } catch(Exception ex) {
    }
}
```

Just as info: I'm using the RootTools found on Google Code for Root Access.

Has anyone an idea how to send these key inputs without root access?

Thanks for any help or advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the security on the android system it it not possible to do this without root access.